# Latex sequence \/?

Tags: latex

This is probably very simple but I couldn't find anything about in the usual latex guides. In this phrase:

```
{\em hello\/}
```

what is the purpose of the "`\/`" ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a so-called italic correction. Its purpose is to ensure proper spacing *after* italic text.

Example:

- `{\itshape M}M` produces *M*M, but italics *M* touches normal M.
- `{\itshape M\/}M` produces *M* M, with a bit more spacing to avoid touching.

Comment: Interesting. and what about \emph{}? does it do the italic correction automatically?

Comment: What about \textit{}? ChkTex is giving me warnings on it.

Comment: Paul—All of the font commands that take an argument insert italic correction automatically. ChkTeX is probably warning you that you should use `\emph` instead or something like that.

Comment: @Will Robertson: Thanks. Actually, it gives warnings about \emph{} as well, so I think its probably just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

`\/` is also the standard macro for separating letters which would otherwise form a ligature, so as said before it acts as a separator. But if you’re using the packages `german`/`ngerman` (deprecated), or `babel` with option `german`/`ngerman` (I don’t know at the moment whether it works on other languages as well) you can take `"|` which generates slightly better spacing and does not influence the hyphenation, as `\/` would.